# How to create a data.frame?

Tags: r

How to create a data.frame that replicates this logic:

```r
row1 = c (1,0,0,0,0)
row2 = c (0,1,0,0,0)
row3 = c (0,0,1,0,0)
row4 = c (0,0,0,1,0)
row5 = c (0,0,0,0,1)
```

so somehow i can set the total number of binary arguments before

Answer (score 1):

We can create a matrix with 0's and assign diagonals to 1

```
nr <- 5
nc <- 5
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nr, nc))
diag(df) <- 1
df

#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  0  0  0  0
#2  0  1  0  0  0
#3  0  0  1  0  0
#4  0  0  0  1  0
#5  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: I am using it this way where I used the vector version and is giving the error: "undefined columns selected" why is this happening?

Comment: @ViniciusSoares What do you mean by "vector version" ? In the above answer you just need to change `nr` to number of rows you want and `nc` to number of columns.

Comment: #the code was like this:
add.constraint(lprec1, c(1,0,0,0,0), "<=", dmd)
add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,1,0,0,0), "<=", dmd)
add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,1,0,0), "<=", dmd)
add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,1,0), "<=", dmd)
add.constraint(lprec1, c(0,0,0,0,1), "<=", dmd)
#and now like this:
nr <- 5
nc <- 5
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, nr, nc))
diag(df) <- 1
add.constraint(lprec1, df, "<=", dmd)

"Error in `[.data.frame`(xt, indices) : undefined columns selected"

apparently R is not recognizing data.frame as a set of vector lines

Comment: I think you could get rid of a line and use diag directly to construct the matrix

Comment: `diag(5)` - \*cough\* - *‘x’ is a scalar (length-one vector) and the only argument, it
          returns a square identity matrix of size given by the scalar.*